# get subcaption for every plot using groupplot pgf tikz after 2020 update

Tags: pgfplots, captions, groupplots

all solutions I find only are from before 2020 and won't work anymore with the latest caption.sty.

I'm gonna start with a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
 
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}  
    \renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
 
\begin{document}
 
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
group style={
group name=my plots,
group size= 3 by 3,
horizontal sep =1.5cm,
vertical sep =2cm},
width=2in
]
\nextgroupplot[]
\addplot[] {x^0};
 
\nextgroupplot[]
\addplot[] {x^1};
 
\nextgroupplot[]
\addplot[] {x^2};
 
\nextgroupplot[]
\addplot[] {x^3};
 
\nextgroupplot[]
\addplot[] {x^4};
 
\nextgroupplot[]
\addplot[] {x^5};
\end{groupplot}
 
% Bildunterschriften
\tikzset{SubCaption/.style={
text width=2in,yshift=-3mm, align=center,anchor=north
}}
 
\node[SubCaption] at (my plots c1r1.south) {\captionof{subfigure}{First graph\label{subplot:eins}}};
 
\node[SubCaption] at (my plots c2r1.south) {\captionof{subfigure}{Second graph\label{subplot:zwei}}};
 
\node[SubCaption] at (my plots c3r1.south) {\captionof{subfigure}{Third graph\label{subplot:drei}}};
 
 
\node[SubCaption] at (my plots c1r2.south) {\captionof{subfigure}{Fourth graph\label{subplot:vier}}};
 
\node[SubCaption] at (my plots c2r2.south) {\captionof{subfigure}{Fifth graph\label{subplot:fuenf}}};
 
\node[SubCaption] at (my plots c3r2.south) {\captionof{subfigure}{Sixth graph\label{subplot:sechs}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{All graphs}\label{fig:plots}
\end{figure}
 
\end{document}
```

(taken from https://www.matheplanet.com/matheplanet/nuke/html/viewtopic.php?topic=236653)

As can be seen there, four years ago this worked so that all single graphs have sub-captions starting with a), but nowadays every caption is an actual figure caption...

I also get an error message for all of these caption lines:
`Package caption Error: Should not be used with subtype 'subfigure'.`

Does anybode know of a currently working solution for captions in a pgf groupplot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\subcaption` instead of `\captionof{subfigure}`. The `\rewnewcommand\thesubfigure` can be commented out.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
 
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}  
%    \renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
 
\begin{document}
 
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
group style={
group name=my plots,
group size= 3 by 3,
horizontal sep =1.5cm,
vertical sep =2cm},
width=2in
]
\nextgroupplot[]
\addplot[] {x^0};
 
\nextgroupplot[]
\addplot[] {x^1};
 
\nextgroupplot[]
\addplot[] {x^2};
 
\nextgroupplot[]
\addplot[] {x^3};
 
\nextgroupplot[]
\addplot[] {x^4};
 
\nextgroupplot[]
\addplot[] {x^5};
\end{groupplot}
 
% Bildunterschriften
\tikzset{SubCaption/.style={
text width=2in,yshift=-3mm, align=center,anchor=north
}}
 
\node[SubCaption] at (my plots c1r1.south) {\subcaption{First graph\label{subplot:eins}}};
 
\node[SubCaption] at (my plots c2r1.south) {\subcaption{Second graph\label{subplot:zwei}}};
 
\node[SubCaption] at (my plots c3r1.south) {\subcaption{Third graph\label{subplot:drei}}};
 
 
\node[SubCaption] at (my plots c1r2.south) {\subcaption{Fourth graph\label{subplot:vier}}};
 
\node[SubCaption] at (my plots c2r2.south) {\subcaption{Fifth graph\label{subplot:fuenf}}};
 
\node[SubCaption] at (my plots c3r2.south) {\subcaption{Sixth graph\label{subplot:sechs}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{All graphs}\label{fig:plots}
\end{figure}
 
\end{document}
```